# View controller error

Tags: uiviewcontroller, error-handling

"Unknown type name 'ViewController' did you mean 'UIViewController'"

Thats the error i get for this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface PurchaseViewController : UIViewController <SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *productTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buyButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *productDescription;
- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProduct *product;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *productID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *homeViewController; //error here
- (void)getProductInfo:(UIViewController *)viewController;
@end
```

Comment: Could you please format this as a question and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Could you show ViewController.h please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the `@interface` statement, put a line like this:

```
@class ViewController;
```

See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the cocoa libraries!

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

That should do the trick.